# Robot does not listen to 2d pose estimate

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when I try to tell it's 2d pose estimate it just stays where it is and show particle clouds around it's wrong location.

that is shown in this image.

I am very new to ros and i'm running out of time where learning step by step is more or less out of my options any help would be appreciated

```
    yinht@yinht-desktop:~$ rosnode info /rviz_1486627152348467684 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Node [/rviz_1486627152348467684]
Publications: 
 * /initialpose [geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped]
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]
 * /goal [geometry_msgs/PoseStamped]

Subscriptions: 
 * /camera/rgb/image_raw [sensor_msgs/Image]
 * /scan2 [unknown type]
 * /move_base/local_costmap/footprint [geometry_msgs/PolygonStamped]
 * /tf [tf2_msgs/TFMessage]
 * /scan [sensor_msgs/LaserScan]
 * /tf_static [tf2_msgs/TFMessage]
 * /particlecloud [geometry_msgs/PoseArray]
 * /map_updates [unknown type]
 * /map [nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid]

Services: 
 * /rviz_1486627152348467684/get_loggers
 * /rviz_1486627152348467684/reload_shaders
 * /rviz_1486627152348467684/set_logger_level


contacting node http://yinht-desktop:41402/ ...
Pid: 27477
Connections:
 * topic: /rosout
    * to: /rosout
    * direction: outbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /tf
    * to: /diffusion_tf (http://yinht-desktop:38259/)
    * direction: inbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /tf
    * to: /camera_base_link2 (http://yinht-desktop:46817/)
    * direction: inbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /tf
    * to: /amcl (http://yinht-desktop:42593/)
    * direction: inbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /tf
    * to: /camera_base_link (http://yinht-desktop:37021/)
    * direction: inbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /tf
    * to: /camera_base_link3 (http://yinht-desktop:43573/)
    * direction: inbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /tf
    * to: /camera_base_link1 (http://yinht-desktop:35271/)
    * direction: inbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /tf
    * to: /robot_state_publisher (http://yinht-desktop:38135/)
    * direction: inbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /tf_static
    * to: /robot_state_publisher (http://yinht-desktop:38135/)
    * direction: inbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /particlecloud
    * to: /amcl (http://yinht-desktop:42593/)
    * direction: inbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /camera/rgb/image_raw
    * to: /camera/camera_nodelet_manager (http://yinht-desktop:41082/)
    * direction: inbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /move_base/local_costmap/footprint
    * to: /move_base (http://yinht-desktop:34315/)
    * direction: inbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /map
    * to: /map_server (http://yinht-desktop:41602/)
    * direction: inbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /scan
    * to: /hokuyo_laser (http://yinht-desktop:44867/)
    * direction: inbound
    * transport: TCPROS
```

[image: image description][image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254189/robot-does-not-listen-to-2d-pose-estimate/) by [Acecryz](https://answers.ros.org/users/28951/acecryz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2017-02-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2017-02-09**:
a bit more information would be appreciated. E.g. what localization are you using? I am guessing `amcl`?

The [`amcl`](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl) inipose topic is `initialpose`. So check that your are actually sending this there.

Also, is `rviz` on a remote machine? This could make a difference too

**Comment by [Acecryz](https://answers.ros.org/users/28951/acecryz/) on 2017-02-09**:
yes I am using amcl, initialpose has a connection to the /amcl. I am not using a remote machine it's on the same PC. I will post my rqt_graph if that helps

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2017-02-09**:
with `rviz` running, please...

**Comment by [Acecryz](https://answers.ros.org/users/28951/acecryz/) on 2017-02-09**:
rviz is running

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2017-02-09**:
but not showing up in the graph. Please configure the graph so that we see it.
Or: `rosnode info /rviz_5468461351` (check to get the right one, should have some numbers trailing).

**Comment by [Acecryz](https://answers.ros.org/users/28951/acecryz/) on 2017-02-09**:
Node [/rviz_5467461351]
Publications: None

Subscriptions: None

Services: None

cannot contact [/rviz_5467461351]: unknown node

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2017-02-09**:
Alright: `rosnode info /rviz_` then hit tab and take the one that actually completes!

**Comment by [Acecryz](https://answers.ros.org/users/28951/acecryz/) on 2017-02-09**:
I updated the question with the `rosnode info /rviz_` sorry I tried using the preformatted text button but it didn't work

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2017-02-09**:
`rostopic info /initialpose`? Any output in `rostopic echo /initialpose` when you send the initial pose via rviz?

**Comment by [Acecryz](https://answers.ros.org/users/28951/acecryz/) on 2017-02-09**:
Type: geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped

Publishers:

- /rviz_1486627152348467684 (http://yinht-desktop:41402/)

Subscribers:

- /amcl (http://yinht-desktop:42593/)

When I try to `rostopic echo /initialpose` it gives a warning that it has not been published yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See answer in [your other question](http://answers.ros.org/question/254179/how-to-make-2d-nav-goal-work/?answer=254204#post-id-254204)

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0